# react native - validate source using digital signature with JWS, bcrypt or react-native-crypto

Tags: validation, react-native, jwt, digital-signature, bcrypt

I am looking for a way to validate the source of a data in my React Native application.
The application receive data in JSON format and I want to validate its source.
I don't need to encrypt the data itself but I want to process only validated data otherwise I will notify the user the data is not originated from a valid source.

I am using RN version 0.45.1

**EDIT**
I've read that its not a good idea to use JWS, for example:

- https://paragonie.com/blog/2017/03/jwt-json-web-tokens-is-bad-standard-that-everyone-should-avoid

but instead use 'react-native-bcrypt' or 'react-native-crypto', the second package is faster??

Comment: If your app is receiving data, it's likely that you know where it came from, i.e. you requested that data from a specific location (http://someurl.com/api/foo) from your react-native app?

Comment: I want to protect from Man in the middle attack. the message/data can be tampered on the way between the sender and the receiver.

Comment: Use Jain web tokens?

Comment: did you mean - JWS
something like this article: "https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec"

Comment: No I mean JSON eve

Comment: can you share a link to an example/article?

Comment: Sorry was typing on mobile. I meant JSON web tokens. Although I will question why you need to validate a response, are you sending sensitive data to the client?

Comment: JWS/JWT and other are all part of JS Object Signing and Encryption framework. I want to make my application safer, and validate the response is one of the ways to do so (in my mind)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of searching I found this solution:
https://github.com/kjur/jsrsasign

this library provides ways to:

generate:
 https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KEYUTIL.html#.generateKeypair

sign and verify:https://kjur.github.io/jsrsasign/api/symbols/KJUR.crypto.Signature.html#constructor:

and many more...